# 'NgModuleFactory' is deprecated

Tags: angular, typescript

what I should use except **NgModuleFactory**? please help me

```
abstract lazyModules: {
        [key: string]: () => Promise<NgModuleFactory<T> | Type<any>>;
    };
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/core/NgModuleFactory

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is multiple approach I would suggest more generic with dynamic

```
abstract lazyModules: {
 [key: string]: ()=> Promise<T>
}

loadModule(name: string){
 return import(`./${name}.module`).then(m => m.MyModule);
}
```

Also you can use generic type parameter instead of the specific `NgModuleFactory` type:

```
abstract lazyModules: {
 [key: string]: ()=> Promise<T>
}
```

Also you can return a promise that resolves to the module class instead of the factory:

```
abstract lazyModules: {
 [key: string]: ()=> Promise<typeof MyModule>
}
```

---

And here is the example if you want to use it

```
const LAZY_MODULE_REF = new InjectionToken('LazyModuleRef')

abstract lazyModules: {
 [key: string]: ()=> Promise<InjectionToken>
};

loadModule(moduleRef: InjectionToken){
 const module = this.injector.get(moduleRef);
}
```

I hope this will help you. Although your questions still need more information but What i can understand might be this will help you.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I want to create dynamic lazy load module and dynamic component which can load dynamically such as a modal that include a component inside